# GridDB Cluster Keeps Resetting

Tags: griddb

I have been working on a personal project and conducting data analysis by storing the data in the GridDB cluster. I created the schema in the cluster, but the cluster keeps resetting, and the names of the columns keep disappearing.

The code for creating the schema is given below:

```js
const factory = griddb.StoreFactory.getInstance();
const store = factory.getStore({
    "host": '239.0.0.1',
    "port": 31999,
    "clusterName": "defaultCluster",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin"
});

// For connecting to the GridDB Server we have to make containers and specify the schema.
const conInfo = new griddb.ContainerInfo({
    'name': "usedcaranalysis",
    'columnInfoList': [
      ["name", griddb.Type.STRING],
      ["Sales_ID", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["name", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["year", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["selling_price", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["km_driven", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["Region", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["State or Province", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["City", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["fuel", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["seller_type", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["transmission", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["owner", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["mileage", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["engine", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["max_power", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
        ["torque", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["seats", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
        ["sold", griddb.Type.STRING]
    ],
    'type': griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, 'rowKey': true
});
```

The error is as follows:

```
[Server]: 10014

[Description] Cluster breakup as a majority of the nodes cannot be secured. Detection of heartbeat error is also recorded just before the event.
```

I have tried creating the cluster once and then creating the container once as well, but I am still getting this error. I even tried restarting the cluster and making the container again, but it did not help either. Any ideas?